# Capture stderr/stdout in pytest within a fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I am having trouble capturing the stderr and stdout for pytest when I am using a fixture.  It works okay if the test is just directly called.  The reason I want it in a fixture is because I need to call it multiple times based on a file that I will be reading.

Here's a working example, lets say this content is in '`test_something.py`':

```
import sys
import pytest


def printing():
    print("testing only")
    print("erroring", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

def test_print(capsys):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as excinfo:
        printing()

    stdout, errout = capsys.readouterr()
    assert stdout == "testing only\n"
    assert errout == "erroring\n"
    assert excinfo.type == SystemExit


class TestPrint():
    @pytest.fixture(name="getResponse", scope="class", params=[0])
    def getResponse(self, request):
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as excinfo:
            printing()
            return excinfo

    def test_print_class(self, getResponse, capsys):
        excinfo = getResponse
        stdout, errout = capsys.readouterr()
        assert stdout == "testing only\n"
        assert errout == "erroring\n"
        assert excinfo.type == SystemExit
```

if you run 'pytest -v' for the above, you get:

```
tests/test_something.py::test_print PASSED                                                                                                                                           [ 50%]
tests/test_something.py::TestPrint::test_print_class[0] FAILED                                                                                                                       [100%]
```

The 'test_print_class' reads empty stdout and stderr, why is that? How can I make it work? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you cannot easily mix function and class scope fixtures.
A function scope fixture would work:

```py
class TestPrint:
    @pytest.fixture(name="getResponse")
    def getResponse(self):
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            printing()

    def test_print_class(self, capsys, getResponse):
        stdout, errout = capsys.readouterr()
        assert stdout == "testing only\n"
        assert errout == "erroring\n"
```

The class scoped fixture is run before the function scoped `capsys` is invoked, so it will not the catch stdout/stderr from the fixture.
The problem is also shown if you try to add `capsys` to the fixture itself. In this case pytest will complain:

> ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'capsys' with a 'class' scoped request object, involved factories

Note that I also removed the `return excinfo` part, as this will never be reached - the context manager scope is left as soon as the exception occurs. The check is also unneeded, because it is already done in the fixture.

So the answer is: it is not possible to achieve what you want this way. Fixtures are there to provide setup/teardown and data for the test, not part of the test itself.
I'm not sure about your actual use case, depending on that you can

- use a function-scoped fixture (if you want to call `printing` for every test, which is what I understood from your question)
- write a separate test for the `printing` exception handling (as you do in the first test), and just use it in the fixture to setup it once for all other tests, if that is what you need